# Not seeing inherited annotations

Tags: java, annotations

I have a class

```
@ReadOnlyViewable(category = "Cache", description = "View the contents of a cache")
public class ReflectingCacheJmx<K, V> extends CacheJmx<K, V> {
```

On which I've added an annotation

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ReadOnlyViewable {
  String description();

  String category();
}
```

I then have a sub class:

```
public class ObservableReflectingCacheJmx<K, V> extends ReflectingCacheJmx<K, V> {
```

And a sub class of that:

```
public class CounterpartyCacheJmx extends ObservableReflectingCacheJmx<CounterpartyKey, Counterparty> {
```

When I take an instance of `CounterpartyCacheJmx` and call `getClass().getAnnotation(ReadOnlyViewable.class)` I get a result of `null`.

On the other hand if I call `getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getAnnotation(ReadOnlyViewable.class)` I get the annotation back.

I thought that `getAnnotation` was supposed to also return annotations on superclasses and `getDeclaredAnnotation` did not.

Is my understanding wrong? Do I need to manually run up the superclass chain myself (or use a 3rd party library to do so) in order to find this annotation?

Spring `ApplicationContext::getBeansWithAnnotation` is returning these beans in the resulting `Map` so that seems to be doing some sort of deep parsing on the annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your annotation is missing the `@Inherited` meta-annotation:

```
@Inherited
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface ReadOnlyViewable {
  String description();

  String category();
}
```

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) on `java.lang.annotation.Inherited`:

> Indicates that an annotation type is automatically inherited. If an Inherited meta-annotation is present on an annotation type declaration, and the user queries the annotation type on a class declaration, and the class declaration has no annotation for this type, then the class's superclass will automatically be queried for the annotation type. This process will be repeated until an annotation for this type is found, or the top of the class hierarchy (Object) is reached.

Having a look at the implementation of `Class.getAnnotation()` you'll eventually encounter `private AnnotationData createAnnotationData(int classRedefinedCount)` which will iterate over the superclass annotations and only adds the annotation if `AnnotationType.getInstance(annotationClass).isInherited()` returns true.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly it. Thanks!